# Is it possible to create a game engine using an existing graphics engine instead of creating a new one

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, game-engine

I just want to create a simple game engine. I have read a lot of articles saying that it will take years for someone to create a game engine. But I just want to know is it possible to create a game engine using an existing graphics engine because I have heard that unity uses Octane Render. If it is possible then how is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create game engine with graphic library like BGFX.
https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx